# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) during mysql installation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, archlinux

I have tried almost all related problems to this problem, but they all weren't working for me.
It's my first time installing mysql onto my arch linux and it keeps asking me for root password as I don't have one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was happening because I wasn't running my terminal in root..

I changed to root user and run the command and everything worked